# parse comma delimited column to insert into table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where the column looks like this:

```
Column 0
2013-11-27 13:11:00,1XRTT,DATA,East Michigan,Region 2,East Michigan_PORT HURON_CL#17,LNS1,2436,DE60XC049,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,76,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,41,35,0,2.59444444444444444444444444444444444444,0,76,0,0,0,168,168,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,155.666666666666666666666666666666666667,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,104,0,0,0,150,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18,0
```

I'd like to parse it to another table with the columns for each of the delimiters. I already have the insert table created, but how do I parse it into the new table?

based on the comment from Mate, I did this

created a function like this:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SplitString_Using_CTE_Charindex]')
AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))
    DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString_Using_CTE_Charindex]
GO

CREATE FUNCTION SplitString_Using_CTE_Charindex (@csv_str VARCHAR(8000),@delimiter varchar(20) )
 RETURNS @splittable TABLE (id int identity(1,1), csvvalues VARCHAR(8000) )
AS
BEGIN  

-- Check for NULL string or empty sting
    IF  (LEN(@csv_str) < 1 OR @csv_str IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        RETURN
    END

    ; WITH csvtbl(i,j)
    AS
    (
        SELECT i=1, j= CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@csv_str+@delimiter) 

        UNION ALL 

        SELECT i=j+1, j=CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@csv_str+@delimiter,j+1)
        FROM csvtbl
        WHERE CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@csv_str+@delimiter,j+1) <> 0
    )   

    INSERT  INTO @splittable  ( csvvalues)
    SELECT  SUBSTRING(@csv_str,i,j-i)
    FROM    csvtbl 

    RETURN
END  

GO
```

then ran this:

```
DECLARE @csv_str VARCHAR(8000)
        ,@delimiter VARCHAR(20)
SET @csv_str = (select * from testimport);

SET @delimiter =','

SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitString_Using_Charindex(@csv_str,@delimiter)
```

but then I got this:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

I did a top 1 in the query too but got this then:

```
Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 43
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.
```

Comment: Check http://prosqlserver.com/blog/2011/02/05/parsing-csv-or-other-delimited-strings-in-sql-server/ . You could a SELECT INTO with function result

Comment: updated the question Mate based on your suggestion...Thanks!

Comment: I guess "select * from testimport" returns more one result. You need a cursor or something to iterate results and call the function for each result... Try with "select top 1 * from testimport" and if works... go for cursor

Comment: Maybe, If you need do that only once, another option is using "sql server import and export wizard"  http://blog.winhost.com/exporting-sql-server-data-with-import-and-export-wizard/ ...

Comment: Hey Mate, I updated the question....also, if I use import export wizard, if I had lets say 20 files, I would have to do that for each of the 20 files, correct?

Comment: @user2061886 So the data is stored in a files or you have the data in SQL Server table and need a function to format it and insert it?

Comment: @user2061886 yes, or merge your 20 files in one and run once.

Answer (score 0):

Two things are wrong. First is that if you are going to assign the results of a query to a varchar variable, you need to guarantee that the query will only return a single value that is a varchar or can be implicitly converted. Right now you are saying "Take this result set that is probably several rows long and stuff it into a single string". You should add a top 1 to the query, but this isn't a long term solution, it's just to test. Eventually you will either need to make this process happen using a cursor to iterate through the results or redesign the function to accept a result table as input. The later would be best especially if you want this to scale at all.

The second problem is that you cannot treat the function as a table to select from. That is why it is giving you the second error. It's like you are trying to select * from count(*) which doesn't really make sense. I would suggest changing this to a stored procedure so you could create a results table and insert into it by calling something like exec SplitString_Using_Charindex @csv_str, @delimiter

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the filesystem, you can use SQL Server's [`BCP`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190919.aspx) tool to dump the data to a flat file and then read it back as comma-delimited.  As you have probably figured out, SQL is not a great tool for text parsing.

```
bcp MySourceTable out C:\tabledump.txt -c -T


BULK INSERT MyDestinationTable
FROM 'C:\tabledump.txt'
WITH (
   DATAFILETYPE='char',
   FIELDTERMINATOR=','
);
```